Are Yubaba and her sister the same person?
Are Yubaba and her sister Zeniba the same person, or does she have a split personality?
Possible spoilers ahead.
Reasons for:

There's a few scenes where Yubaba leaves and then returns but it doesn't tell you where she goes off too.
The house looks like the opposite of the hotel
They are never in the same shot together
Her rings and her sister's rings are exactly the same

Reasons against:

Haku has a mission to get something from Yubaba's sister
The paper dolls follow Haku back to the hotel
Yubaba's sister invites No Face to stay


According to Miyazaki (via the Ghibli Wiki), they're two different people, albeit modelled on precisely the same animated character for financial reasons.

"Ultimately , when we were getting down to the wire in the latter half of the production, Masashi Ando, the animation director, begged me not to add new characters. So I created a twin for Yubaba. Of course, in retrospect, it could have been taller, older sister and not just a twin. But either way, it's still really like two faces of the same person. When we're at work like Yubaba, yelling and making a mess and getting people to work, but when we go home we try to be good citizens. This schism is the painful part of being human." Some people who live a calm life like Zeniba at home may treat their subordinates as strict bosses like Yubaba while facing stress at work.

He does point out that he was worried that audiences might be confused since they're literally just the same animation model (albeit with some audio and visual cues to tell the audience that they're not the same person).

"Taking Yubaba as a single character, we spent ten times more time connected to her, observing her, and thinking about how to depict her, than we did actually drawing storyboards for her-so much so that I don't even remember how far we developed her in the storyboards."
"We skipped all explanations (on the fact) that Yubaba and Zeniba are really the same person. I'm that way too. I'm completely a different person when I'm at Ghibli, when I'm at home, and when I'm out and about in the community. In fact, I live in amost schizoid fashion. I was worried about how children would accept this aspect of the movie, but they seem to have accepted it with no problem at all, so I've been greatly relieved.".


Um, you're kinda sending mixed messages here.

@Mithoron - They've reused the same animation model but they're supposed to be two distinct people.

Yeah, but if someone only noticed the bold bit...

Oh, it's even bold and slanted, while "different" is only slanted. If some one didn't read carefully...

@Mithoron - See edit

They aren't literally the same person in the fiction of the story, but they are two faces of the same person on the metaphorical level.

“may treat their subordinates as strict bosses like Zeniba” should read “may treat their subordinates as strict bosses like Yubaba”. The Wiki page you're quoting makes the same mistake.

@MarkDominus - Feel free to make small corrections if you can show a better source

It would be interesting to ask the animation staff who have worked under Miyazaki which one he is. Heheh
